# Why I am getting FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient,?

Tags: .net

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have the dll file in the folder

[image]

Comment: Why don't you get the `System.Data.SqlClient` via Nuget?

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I did that

Comment: I think you shouldn't put and deal with this DLL under your `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin it is nt under the root folder

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` has dependencies and I don't believe it can be used as standalone.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin how can i fix the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254055/discussion-between-mustafa-ozcetin-and-user123456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` library instead of `System.Data.SqlClient` should resolve the issue.